# How should I remove a wooden fence from a tree trunk?

Tags: fence, tree

I have a wooden fence that has been attached to a walnut tree trunk that was growing on the fence-line (wasn't my decision - was the builders).

That stump is now rotten and we would like to get it removed, but to do that we need to take the fence off the trunk. What is the best way to get this done, and if I go the road of paying someone to do this, what would be a reasonable rate to pay?

Comment: A wooden fence and a rotted tree= chain saw to me.

Comment: Can you add a picture? That my help. If the stump isn't to big, you can try [stump remover](https://www.amazon.com/Spectracide-Stump-Remover-Granules-HG-66420/dp/B004GVYXKC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1472154111&sr=8-1&keywords=stump+remover), but that may damage the wooden fence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to agree with Ed, with the added suggestion that a SawzAll might be used on the fencing if nails are an issue, or if you don't have a chain saw. The smaller size might also work better if the clearances between objects that are being cut are such that a chain saw might be unwieldy.

But, yeah, chain saw rules otherwise.

Be safe,
Bill